# Errors with tcblisting and tabstackengine

Tags: errors, tcolorbox, stackengine

I want to use the `tabstackengine` package in a `tcblisting` environment, but get a lot of error messages. How can I make this work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\stackMath
\setstacktabbedgap{0.5em}
\setstackTAB{ }

\begin{document}



\begin{tcblisting}{title=System of linear equations,text side listing}
  \[
\tabbedCenterstack[r]{
  \text{I:}     -2x +  y + 3z = 10 + x \\ 
  \text{II' = I + II:}     x +  y +  z =  6 + 2z\\
  \text{III:}     3 + 3y + 2z = y - 3z 
}\]
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Error messages:

```
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\\->\let \reserved@e 
                     \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserved...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\\->\let \reserved@e \relax \let \reserved@f 
                                             \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserved...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Use of \\tabbedCenterstack doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Use of \\tabbedCenterstack doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def \reserved@a *
                             {\let \reserved@e \vadjust \let \reserved@f \no...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \def \reserved@a *{\let \reserved@e 
                                               \vadjust \let \reserved@f \no...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...eserved@e \vadjust \let \reserved@f 
                                                  \nobreak \@xnewline }\rese...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Use of \\tabbedCenterstack doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Use of \@newline doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@processROW has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
||\expandafter \ifstrempty \expandafter {\@postSEP }{\toggletrue {@do\ETC.
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@processROW was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@processTABrow has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
||\global \csedef {TABX\row@ID X\roman {TABcellindex@}}{\expandonce \@preTAB \ETC.
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@processTABrow was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@processTABrow has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
||\global \csedef {TABX\row@ID X\roman {TABcellindex@}}{\expandonce \@preTAB \ETC.
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@processTABrow was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\set@tabularcellalignment ...ef \tabular@settings 
                                                  {#1.}\whileboolexpr {test ...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\set@tabularcellalignment ...ef \tabular@settings 
                                                  {\expandafter \@gobble \ta...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\set@tabularcellalignment ...le \tabular@settings 
                                                  .}}\expandafter \@getnextT...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\set@tabularcellalignment ...ar \tabular@settings 
                                                  \\\if l\@nextTABchar \edef...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@getnextTABchar has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
\if l\@nextTABchar \edef \stackalignment {l}\else \if r\@nextTABchar \ETC.
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@getnextTABchar was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\\->\let \reserved@e 
                     \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserved...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\\->\let \reserved@e \relax \let \reserved@f 
                                             \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserved...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Use of \\tabbedCenterstack doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Use of \\tabbedCenterstack doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def \reserved@a *
                             {\let \reserved@e \vadjust \let \reserved@f \no...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \def \reserved@a *{\let \reserved@e 
                                               \vadjust \let \reserved@f \no...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...eserved@e \vadjust \let \reserved@f 
                                                  \nobreak \@xnewline }\rese...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Use of \\tabbedCenterstack doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Use of \@newline doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 }
     \]
Runaway argument?
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.6 }
     \]
./tabbedstacked.listing:6: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.6 }
     \]
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
./tabbedstacked.listing:6:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on tabbedstacked.log.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 256
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 12 at Mon Aug 29 23:51:19
```

Comment: The current version of `tabstackengine` , 2016/11/30 (V2.01), is more robust and works OK with the original code of the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tcblisting (like e.g. minipage) calls internally `\@parboxrestore`, which sets `\\` to `\@normalcr`. Unlike `\\` `\@normalcr` is not robust and so the code of stackengine breaks. Making `\@normalcr` robust avoids the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabstackengine}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\stackMath
\setstacktabbedgap{0.5em}
\setstackTAB{ }

\makeatletter
\robustify{\@normalcr} %globally robust
%avoids error but wrong output:
%\def\@parboxrestore{\@arrayparboxrestore\def\\{\protect\@normalcr}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{title=System of linear equations,text side listing}
  \[
\tabbedCenterstack[r]{
  \text{I:}     -2x +  y + 3z = 10 + x \\
  \text{II' = I + II:}     x +  y +  z =  6 + 2z\\
  \text{III:}     3 + 3y + 2z = y - 3z
}
\]
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

I don't know why `\@normalcr` wasn't robust from the start and it is possible that a redefinition can have side effects. In this case stackengine will have to make it robust locally or change the code that scans for the EOL.

Comment: The redefinition of `\@parboxrestore` doesn't work; with `\robustify` the result is wrong anyway.

Comment: @egreg You are right redefining \@parboxrestrore not enough -- I only looked at the errors. But what you mean regarding \robustify? That the lines are too long?

Comment: Yes, the math display overlaps the code part. The `\robustify` method, which applies `\protected`, should not have any particular side effect, because `\protected` macros obey `\expandafter` (which is not the case for the legacy protection mechanism in LaTeX2e that uses `\protect`). A `\protected` macro is not expanded only in `\edef` or `\write` contexts.

Comment: @egreg: The width is a tcolorbox question, one need to set e.g. the `lefthand width` (or move the code above the output).

Comment: Two observations:1) to avoid conflicting EOL characters, `stackengine` has `\setstackEOL{\cr}` for example, to change the stacking EOL notation; and 2) a `%` after the opening `{` of the `\tabbedCenterstack` will help resolve the alignment.

Comment: Thus, try `\[
\setstacktabbedgap{0.15em}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\tabbedCenterstack[r]{%
  \text{I:}     -2x +  y + 3z = 10 + x \cr
  \text{II'\,=\,I\,+\,II:}     x +  y +  z =  6 + 2z\cr
  \text{III:}     3 + 3y + 2z = y - 3z
}
\]` without any of the `\makeatletter` stuff.

Comment: Note that the current `tabstackengine` version, 2016/11/30 (V2.01), no longer suffers this issue.